# Hibernate - failed to lazily initialize - no session or session was closed

Tags: hibernate, jsf, lazy-loading

i've found weird condition of my hibernate program. Here's my code

```
public Set<AnotherClass> getAnotherClassSetsFromSomeClass() {
        Session session = HIbernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction trans = session.beginTransaction();
        SomeClass sc = (SomeClass)session.get(SomeClass.class,"classId");
        trans.commit();
        session.close;
        return sc.getAnotherClassSet();
    }
```

This code looking fine if i run it on Java Console.

If i'm used it one web app (JSF),i got this error

**failed to lazily initialize - no session or session was closed**

*It has One to Many Relation (One SomeClass has Many AnotherClass)*

The exception message pointed to return `sc.getAnotherClassSet()` as a null pointer. I'm sured that i have that data in my database.

Well i found that if i add `System.out.println(sc.getAnotherClassSet())` berfore `return sc.getAnotherClassSet()` my code is working fine.

Any idea what happened ? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably, your `@OneToMany` association is mapped with `fetchType="lazy"` (maybe by default). It means that the association, in your case `AnotherClassSet`, is not loaded when you load the entity `SomeClass`. It is only loaded when you try to access it, using `getAnotherClassSet()`.

However, in your example, this method (`getAnotherClassSet()`) is called on the `return` statment, after the session was closed.

To solve this issue, you can try to invoke `getAnotherClassSet()` before closing the session, just to load the `AnotherClassSet` association.

Comment: This is the answer, but instead invoke getter or setter, better use the class attribute with some function, like getAnotherClassSet().size() and it will loaded to AnotherClassSet in SomeClass. Thanks

Comment: Yes, loading the `AnotherClassSet` association (of `SomeClass`) is what I tried to suggest in the last paragraph of my answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Because, you are using `lazy initialization`(which is default setting). In `lazy initialization`, every collection field is fetched upon request only. You have to specify initialization as `eager`, for your code to work. `Eager initialization` fetches the entire object in a single fetch.

Comment: can you explain why if i add System.out.println() before return, my code is working ?

Comment: After closing session i.e. `session.close()`, you cannot fetch anything.